# How to accept input from user on command line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing some code in JavaScript and running it using the command line using the command `node filename.js`. I want the user to enter input values on the command line and use these values for further process and output.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/accept-input-from-the-command-line-in-nodejs

Comment: you want the user input as a parameter to script i.e. `node filename.js --p1 param1 --p2 param2` or in the console. i.e. user runs the script the asked for the first param then second and so on?

Comment: @AZ_ I want input in the console and want to accept multiple values one by one

Comment: then you can use `readline` module as suggested by @CodeF0x

Comment: @AZ_ readline also allowing only one input. I want to stop console printing next sentence until first question answered and after answering first question then second and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [prompts](https://github.com/terkelg/prompts#readme) npm package

`npm install --save prompts`

```
const prompts = require('prompts');

const questions = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'dish',
    message: 'Do you like pizza?'
  },
  {
    type: prev => prev == 'pizza' ? 'text' : null,
    name: 'topping',
    message: 'Name a topping'
  }
];

(async () => {
  const response = await prompts(questions);
})();
```

Comment: I'm getting error as below:                                             
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
       throw err;
       ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'prompts'

Comment: cd into your project folder & run `npm install --save prompts` then try again

Comment: Yes it did worked. But how can I get values entered by the user?

Comment: Thanks. I got it.